# Having saved a dataframe to hdfs I have an error when I try to unserialize it when reading it back in using rhdfs

Tags: r, hadoop, serialization

I have written a dataframe into hdfs using the rhdfs library and when I try to read it back in I have errors.

The code to write the dataframe is as follows,

```
df.file <- hdfs.file("/mydir/df.Rdata", "w")
hdfs.write(df, df.file)
hdfs.close(df.file)
```

And to read it back in I use

```
df.file <- hdfs.file("/mydir/df.Rdata", "r")
m <- hdfs.read(df.file)
df <- unserialize(m)
hdfs.close(df.file)
```

But I get an error at the unserialize stage,

```
Error in unserialize(m) : read error
```

Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this error is and what I can do to prevent it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a small and minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I actually can't I have been trying there for a while.  My dataset is quite big and is initially read into R from hdfs.  I tried a small sample of it and just got errors.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the object you unserialize is bigger than 65536 bytes

If you look at the RStudio Environment, you will see that df object is raw[1:65536] and you missed a part of the file

you should read it by pieces like this code:

http://chingchuan-chen.github.io/posts/2015/04/08/installations-of-rhdfs-rmr2-plyrmr-and-hbase